# Erased all partitions and the partition table on the external hard disc

Tags: linux, mount, partition, guid-partition-table

How to create a partition on an external hard disc and mount it in linux when all the partitions and the partition table are erased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the usual way. Just connect the external disk drive to the Linux machine and verify it shows up in the output of `lsblk`. Then you can format it via `fdisk` (or any other partitioning tool), and then create a filesystem on it via `mkfs`. Eventually, you `mount` it and the disk is ready to use.

Comment: I think he meant that he accidently destroyed the partition tables. In that case you can recreate the partition table with fdisk (or gdisk) if you enter the EXACT same values as before. That would recreate the partition table and your (ext4 or whatever) fs will still be there in the partitions. In fact, you can gamble the sizes and just try to mount it, one partition at a time. If the mount fails then the start of the partition is wrong and you can try again.